# how can i remove duplicate values by using distinct keyword

Tags: mysql

I have a table with records like this

```
*************************** 1. row *************************

   did: 98

 brand_name: Aarther P (100+500)

generic: Paracetamol, Aceclofenac

tradename: Aarther P (100+500)

manfactured: Rekvina Pharmaceuticals

unit: 500mg/100mg

type: Tablet

quantity: 10Tablet

 price: 27.9

*************************** 2. row *************************

did: 99

brand_name: Aarther-P

generic: Aceclofenac, Paracetamol

tradename: Aarther-P

manfactured: Rekvina Pharmaceuticals

unit: 100mg/500mg

type: Tablet

quantity: 10Tablet

price: 27.9

*************************** 3. row ************************

did: 100

brand_name: Aarticef (1000mg)

generic: NULL

tradename: Aarticef (1000mg)

manfactured: Alpic Remedies Ltd

unit: 1000mg/vial

type: Injection

quantity: 1Vial

price: 96
```

I want to eliminate duplicate manfactured names,for that I have executed the following query

```
select brand_name,generic,manfactured from drugs_info group by
manfactured;
```

But it is displaying 1st and 3rd records only like follow, but I want 2nd record

```
*************************** 1. row *************************

did: 98

 brand_name: Aarther P (100+500)

generic: Paracetamol, Aceclofenac

tradename: Aarther P (100+500)

manfactured: Rekvina Pharmaceuticals

unit: 500mg/100mg

type: Tablet

quantity: 10Tablet

 price: 27.9

*************************** 3. row ************************

 did: 100

 brand_name: Aarticef (1000mg)

generic: NULL

tradename: Aarticef (1000mg)

manfactured: Alpic Remedies Ltd

unit: 1000mg/vial

type: Injection

quantity: 1Vial

price: 96
```

How can I write select query for my requirement.

Comment: you want to eliminate duplicate manfactured names include did or brand_name or which column?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(select brand_name,generic,manfactured from drugs_info ORDER BY did DESC) abc
 group by manfactured;
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete duplicates in mysql, use mysql's multiple table delete syntax:

```
delete d2
from mytable d1
join mytable d2 on d2.manfactured = d1.manfactured
    and d2.did > d1.did
```

The extra join condition of `d2.did > d1.did` ensures both that rows do not join to themselves, and that only one half of each duplicate is deleted, but also that the lowest id row is kept.